# Custom Magento Shell Script - can't get argument value

Tags: mage-shell, magento-ee

I'm attempting to create a custom shell script that will extract a zip file in my `media/tmp` directory.

I've created a labeler.php file in the shell directory. It extends `Mage_Shell_Abstract` and run() looks like this:

```
/**
 * Run script
 *
 */
public function run()
{
    $_SESSION = array();
    if ($this->getArg('unzip')) {
        $zipFile = strval($this->getArg('unzip'));
        echo "Unzipping {$zipFile}";
    }elseif ($this->getArg('pendingList')) {
        echo "this\n";
    } else {
        echo $this->usageHelp();
    }
}
```

The command that I am executing from is `php -f shell/labeler.php -- unzip file.zip`. The output that I get is: *Unzipping 1*

Comment: What if you don't use `strval` on the argument ?

Comment: I added strval because the output was `1`. I probably should have removed it from my example above.

Comment: What if you run `php -f shell/labeler.php --unzip file.zip` (without the space between `--` and `unzip`) ?

Comment: Or more probably like this : `php -f shell/labeler.php -- --unzip file.zip`

Comment: Your last suggestion works perfectly. Any idea why? Prior to posting `php -f shell/labeler.php -- unzip file.zip` and `php -f shell/labeler.php unzip file.zip` produced the same output of `1`. And `php -f shell/labeler.php --unzip file.zip` outputs usage suggestions. Which is bothersome because I don't see how my code is different from the model I followed in indexer.php

Comment: see my edited answer for details ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From what I know I think the right syntax is the following:

```
php -f shell/labeler.php -- --unzip file.zip
```

The syntax for shell script in Magento is :

```
php -f script.php -- [options]
```

Where options could be just a flag like this:

```
php -f script.php -- test
```

In that case `$this->getArg('test')` will return 1 (true).

Or it could be a value like this:

```
php -f script.php -- --test mytest
```

In that case `$this->getArg('test')` will return 'mytest'

Comment: I'll accept your answer when enough time has passed. This has earned a permanent home in my `@link` phpDoc.